# Problem with x axis on swarmplot and added line with seaborn

Tags: python, visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to add custom lines to seaborn swarmplot (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36152188/993324) answer) and it seems that x axis is wrongly scaled.

Data preparation:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()

X_full = pd.DataFrame(data = iris["data"], columns = iris["feature_names"])
y_full = pd.Series(data = iris["target"])

# selecting two classes and two features
y = y_full[(y_full == 0) | (y_full == 1)]
X = X_full[["sepal width (cm)", "petal width (cm)"]].loc[y.index]
```

and actual plot:

```
import seaborn as sns

grid = sns.JointGrid(x = X["sepal width (cm)"], y = X["petal width (cm)"])
grid = grid.plot_joint(sns.swarmplot, hue = y)

xmin = X["sepal width (cm)"].min() 
xmax = X["sepal width (cm)"].max()

ymin = X["petal width (cm)"].min()
ymax = X["petal width (cm)"].max()

grid.ax_joint.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], 'b-', linewidth = 2)

grid.ax_joint.plot([xmin, xmax], [ymin, ymax] )
```

Result:

[image]

Thin line should go from (xmin, ymin) to (xmax,ymax). On the **y** axis it looks correct, but **x** axis is wrong.

How to fix plot so coordinates will be plotted correctly?